# jQuery-UI slider handle duplicates at maximum

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a problem with my jQuery-UI slider. I am using this slider to specify which color should be made. I am using HSB so the hue slider ranges from 0 to 360. Now this all works fine, I use the percentage to calculate the amount of hue.

When the user left the page, I am saving the value somewhere so when they return to the webpage, they didn't lose their progress with the bars. This part works semi-fine. The problem is, when they left the page at 360 (so 100% for the slider) and then move the slider to the left, the handle duplicates.

Normal **works fine**:
[image]

360 **works semi-fine**:
[image]

After returning to the page and moving the slider **duplicated handle**:
[image]

**My JavaScript when initializing:**

```
$.get("get.php", function(data){
    var percentage = (parseInt(data) / 360) * 100;
    $("#hue").slider({
        step: 0.01,
        maximum: 100,
        minimum: 0,
        slide: function(){ setBox();},
        change: function(){ setBox(); updateCookie(); ch.restore(); },
        value: percentage
    });
});
```

*get.php returns a value between 0 and 360, which I then take the percentage of.*

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="hue"><canvas id="choose" width="1730"></canvas></div>
    <div id="mixedColor"><input type="text" id="input" /></div>
    <div id="hueCSV"><canvas id="bitmap" width="1730"></canvas></div>
    <div id="csvColor"><input type="text" id="input_csv" readonly /></div>  
</div>
```